# SelectList Object selectedValue issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, selectlist

I'm having troubles with the selectedValue option for SelectedItems, for some reason it won't select the item despite it being in the list...

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateTransformer(string edit)
{    
            var equipment = GenIDQueries.FindEquipment(edit);
            ViewData["Feeder"] = new SelectList(GenIDQueries.GetFeeders(equipment.OpsCentre.ToString()),
                                                "CircuitID",
                                                "CircuitDescription",
                                                equipment.Feeder);
        return View(equipment);
    }
```

equipment.Feeder is of type Integer.

My View:

```
<p>
                <b><%=Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Feeder) %>:</b><font color="red">*</font>
                <%=Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Feeder, ViewData["Feeder"] as SelectList, "") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Feeder)%>
            </p>
```

My GenIDQueries.GetFeeders:

```
public static IEnumerable<Circuit> GetFeeders(string distNo)
        {
            int distNoNumber;
            if ( int.TryParse(distNo, out distNoNumber))
            {
                return ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Circuit>()
                .Where(x => x.DistrictCircuitRelations
                          .Any(y => y.District.DistrictNo == distNoNumber))
                .OrderBy(x => x.CircuitDescription)
                .Select(x => new Circuit
                {
                    CircuitID = x.CircuitID,
                    CircuitDescription = x.CircuitDescription
                });
            }
            return new List<Circuit>();
        }
```

I have verified that the element I wanted to select is indeed returned by GenIDQueries, however when the page loads it never selects that option, in the HTML source code, the item is not selected either.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

When setting the selected value you should set it to the selected `CircuitID` and not the Feeder object.

Comment: Yeah it is. The funny thing is, I placed the new Selectlist into a variable, and it even shows that the item is Selected, but when the page loads it does not select it

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using this [Plague of ViewData](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plague_%28disease%29)? I consider `ViewData` as a virus started at Microsoft open space laboratories and spread through internet blog posts and articles.

View models are the way to go in ASP.NET MVC:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateTransformer(string edit)
{    
    var equipment = GenIDQueries.FindEquipment(edit);
    var items = GenIDQueries.GetFeeders(equipment.OpsCentre.ToString());
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        SelectedValue = equipement.CircuitID,
        Items = new SelectList(items, "CircuitID", "CircuitDescription")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CircuitID, Model.Items, "") %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CircuitID) %>
```

Comment: I agree with you that ViewData is a plague, I only used this method to debug my case. If I placed the following into the View: new SelectList(GenIDQueries.GetFeeders("1"), "CircuitID", "CircuitDescription", Model.Feeder) the SelectList finds the item, and the item's property for "Selected" is true, but when the page loads the item is not selected

Comment: As a newcomer to MVC2, I'd certainly like to learn about your perspective on ViewData. But posting a link titled "Plague of ViewData" that links to a wikipedia article about plague gets you a down-vote from me, as that's quite mis-leading. If you're asserting that ViewData should be avoided, please ellaborate why, or post a real reference -- I'll turn the down to an up if you do.